# Combine two tables based on certain criteria using python

Tags: python, pandas, path, filenames

I have two tables (table1, table2) of the following:

table1:

| ID | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 12345.txt |
| 12346 | 12346.txt |
| 12347 | 12347.txt |
| 12348 | 12348.txt |
| 12349 | 12349.txt |
| 12350 | 12350.txt |

table2: contains the path where table 1 files are present

| Path |
| --- |
| /table/text3/12349.txt |
| /table/text1/12345.txt |
| /table/text2/12346.txt |
| /table/text1/12350.txt |
| /table/text3/12347.txt |
| /table/text1/12348.txt |

How do I combine these two files, such that, the path and filenames are matched. What I tried so far?

```
pd.concat([table1, table2])
```

I also tried  `pd.merge` but it does not match with the filename. How do I solve this?

The desired output:

| ID | Filename | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 12345.txt | /table/text1/12345.txt |
| 12346 | 12346.txt | /table/text2/12346.txt |
| 12347 | 12347.txt | /table/text3/12347.txt |
| 12348 | 12348.txt | /table/text1/12348.txt |
| 12349 | 12349.txt | /table/text3/12349.txt |
| 12350 | 12350.txt | /table/text1/12350.txt |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a temporary column `Filename` on `df2` by [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and use the resulting copy of `df2` with newly added column to merge with `df1` using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the common column `Filename`, as follows:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2.assign(Filename=df2['Path'].str.split('/').str[-1]), on='Filename')
```

Result:

```
print(df_merge)



      ID   Filename                    Path
0  12345  12345.txt  /table/text1/12345.txt
1  12346  12346.txt  /table/text2/12346.txt
2  12347  12347.txt  /table/text3/12347.txt
3  12348  12348.txt  /table/text1/12348.txt
4  12349  12349.txt  /table/text3/12349.txt
5  12350  12350.txt  /table/text1/12350.txt
```

### Edit

If you still want to show the entries of `df1` even when there is no matching entries in `df2`, you can use left merge with parameter `how='left'`, as follows:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2.assign(Filename=df2['Path'].str.split('/').str[-1]), on='Filename', how='left')
```

Result:

**If the path /table/text3/12347.txt is missing:**

```
      ID   Filename                    Path
0  12345  12345.txt  /table/text1/12345.txt
1  12346  12346.txt  /table/text2/12346.txt
2  12347  12347.txt                     NaN
3  12348  12348.txt  /table/text1/12348.txt
4  12349  12349.txt  /table/text3/12349.txt
5  12350  12350.txt  /table/text1/12350.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But, it does not work if some of the rows in table2 are missing. For example, if the path ```/table/text3/12347.txt``` is missing, then it does not merge the two files. How do I solve that?

Comment: @disukumo  Good! You've taken a good choice for my solution adhering to the order of columns you want.

Comment: @disukumo  `Path` is the only information in `df2`.  If there is missing entries there, how can we get a criteria to merge them ?

Comment: @disukumo  I guess you want to still have all entries of `df1` even when there is no matching entries in `df2`.    See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `Filename` and then do the merge:

```
merged_df = df2.assign(Filename = df2['Path'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[-1]).merge(df1, on = 'Filename')
```

Option via `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
merged_df = df2.assign(Filename = df2['Path'].apply(lambda x: Path(x).name)).merge(df1, on = 'Filename')
```

OUTPUT:

```
                     Path   Filename     ID
0  /table/text3/12349.txt  12349.txt  12349
1  /table/text1/12345.txt  12345.txt  12345
2  /table/text2/12346.txt  12346.txt  12346
3  /table/text1/12350.txt  12350.txt  12350
4  /table/text3/12347.txt  12347.txt  12347
5  /table/text1/12348.txt  12348.txt  12348
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But, it does not work if some of the rows in table2 are missing. For example, if the path ```/table/text3/12347.txt``` is missing, then it does not merge the two files. How do I solve that?